# How to save output of javascript to a text file?

Tags: javascript

I am not a programmer, so please forgive me if my question is too silly. I have created a very simple website which takes the first name, last name and then a very simple javascript file says `Thank You <first name> <last name>` and done. I figured HTML through YouTube videos and found this javascript

```
    function signFunction(firstName, lastName){
    alert("Thank you , " + firstName + " " + lastName + "!");       
}
```

I just want to know how can I save the output of `javascript` to a text file. I am using Apache in Debian.

Comment: Javascript can't write to files directly. It needs to use a form submission or AJAX to send the data to a script that runs on the server, and the server script can save to a file.

Comment: @Barmar This is untrue. Files can be saved using the `saveAs` DOM function, as well as generating dynamic `data:` URIs with an "attachment" content-disposition. There is also the `Blob` API as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Create and save file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file)

Comment: Are you trying to save to a file on the server or the client machine?

Comment: @Barmar to a text file on my Debian server

Comment: @Dai Your duplicate is for saving on the client, he wants to save on the server.

Comment: @THECOMPTGUY In that case my first comment is correct, you need a server-side script to save the file.

Comment: @Barmar, so there is no simple script to save?

Comment: No, there's nothing that does this automatically. Clients aren't supposed to be able to write directly to a server, it's supposed to be mediated by the application running on the server.